# How to create a library with shared code in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-libraries, project-structure, adobe-animate

Say I want to create a `library.swf` file that will contain most of the definitions for images, sprites and (most importantly) code for custom components, that will be used by other sub projects by only linking the `library.swf` asset without actually importing anything in the resulting SWF file.

Here is the naive way I tried with Adobe Animate:

1. Create `library` project.
2. Create scripts needed.
3. Add scripts to project files without specifying main script of the main scene.

Expectedly, last step caused troubles because nowhere in the application I see a way to add scripts.  The most promising is Library tab where I can add `New Symbol...`, but I would think I don't need to create MoveClip for every script I want to add.

In the meanwhile I was trying to find a way I could use this library in other projects, which I believe must be done by importing assets, but the same problem again - I can't find a way to import/reference some SWF file from which I can `import` packages.

Do I need some other IDE, say FlashDevelop, or is there a way inside Adobe Animate I totally missed?

Comment: Probably, this: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/sharing-library-assets-across-files.html

Comment: @Organis I've tried the approach from the link and it doesn't seem to work for sharing scripts :/

Comment: Why? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: @Organis so I add new symbol, choose MovieClip, save file to `Common/SomeClass.as`. The class does not extend MovieClip cuz that's not what I need. I add code, save it again, export to SWF. But when I reopen this script, it is empty dummy script that extends MovieClip. And when I look via JPEXS decompiler, the script is in the root, and not in Common package, but this might be due to `Name` field during creation where I can't supply full path

Comment: You cannot add an item to the Library and **NOT** extend **MovieClip** or **Sprite**. In order to add other classes to the project, you need to, for example, **import** them in the first frame of main timeline (and maybe refer them, I don't remember).

Comment: @Organis not even a `Shape`? Or a `SimpleButton`?

Comment: **Shape** is not an item you can put to the **Library** it exists only at runtime. **SimpleButton**... maybe. **Sound** (you export audio by subclassing it), **BitmapData** (raster images), **Font** (embedded text fonts).

Comment: @Organis "You cannot add an item to the Library and NOT extend MovieClip" - what I assumed :( So for a symbol I extend MovieClip, but whenever I save the script to a certain location other than root, `Edit Class` option will always open new file, but not the one I saved. Do I have to save all scripts at root level?

Comment: You can save your AS3 classes to the multiple places, but you need to understand how packages work in order to do it properly: https://www.h3xed.com/programming/actionscript-3-beginner-introduction-to-package-and-classes

Comment: @Organis yea, I use packages that are named the same as the folder path, but the app still does not see scripts. I didn't setup document class, I think it might cause issues, but I don't need document class in a library

Comment: Main document class should not be in the **Library** anyway. Then, in the **Library**, do you link AS3 classes via their full name, like **my.good.package.ClassName** or just **ClassName**?

Comment: @Organis `Linkage`. It put _ClassName_ there by default even if I chose directory during creation, and I tried putting path with slashes there. And I was wondering what was it for. Awesome, this problem is solved! But now the follow up which I believe still falls under main question: how do I import use this library as an asset in other projects?

Comment: Once you actually **CAN** buld the SWF with all classes/assets you want, you can get back to the first link I provided. It explains how to use RSL-linked assets.

Comment: @Organis I followed through that article and I believe sharing at author-time is the thing I am looking for: shared asset is only stored in library, target file only links library file and does not copies shared assets in a resulting SWF. Actually, I initially looked for a ways that result in ImportAsset2 tag being added to the SWF (as described [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2887%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C52%2C529%2C0%5D))

Comment: Then you need to change library linkage type from RSL to Embed or Import, I don't remember exactly. Then Flash will add the external resources to the project it builds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220366/discussion-between-lolbas-and-organis).

Comment: @lolbas **not clear**... Are you trying to have a `library.swf` which contains a `myfunction()` that you later want to call from any other second project as long as that 2nd project simply loads `library.swf`? So 2nd project can have code like `myValue = theLibrarySWF.myfunction();`? Is that what you want to achieve? Running functions that exists in some loaded external SWF?

Comment: @VC.One hey, my more [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63641147) question has better details, but to answer your question: more like `library.swf` defines `BaseWindow` class which I can then use in 2nd project like `class CustomWindow extends BaseWindow`