# Properly link SWF library when compiling Actionscript 3 Air poject using as3mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, air

In my attempts to achieve the following:

- compile `library.swf` that contains different common scripts;
- compile different SWFs that link `library.swf` and use these common scripts without copying code to own resulting SWFs;

I was trying to use `acompc` and `mxmlc`, however I couldn't achieve the approach above.

Recently I came up across as3mxml plugin for Visual Studio Code (VSC) which I gave a try as at least it had some examples. Here is my MVP:

Project `library` that builds `library.swf`, `library.swc` and `catalog.xml`

`src/Common/Label.as`:

```
package Common {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    
    public class Label extends Sprite {
        
        public function Label(text:String, x:Number, y:Number) {
            var display_txt:TextField = new TextField();
            display_txt.text = text;
            display_txt.x = x;
            display_txt.y = y;
            addChild(display_txt);
        }
    }
}
```

`asconfig.json`:

```
{
    "type": "lib",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "swf-version": 11,
        "source-path": [
            "src"
        ],
        "include-sources": [
            "src"
        ],
        "warnings": false,
        "debug": false,
        "use-network": false,
        "output": "bin/library.swc"
    }
}
```

The library builds the way I want it to, so seemingly no problems here.

Project `HelloWorld` that builds `HelloWorld.swf`

`src/HelloWorld.as`:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import Common.Label;
    
    public class HelloWorld extends MovieClip {
        public function HelloWorld() {
            var label:Label = new Label("Hello World", 5, 5);
            addChild(label);
        }
    }
}
```

`asconfig.json`:

```
{
    "config": "air",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "swf-version": 11,
        "source-path": [
            "src"
        ],
        "external-library-path": [
            "../library/bin/library.swc"
        ],
        "static-link-runtime-shared-libraries": false,
        "output": "bin/HelloWorld.swf"
    },
    "mainClass": "HelloWorld"
}
```

With this setup, VSC successfully code-completes the `Label` class, the `library` and `HelloWorld` are built successfully, but the `HelloWorld.swf` has no linkage to library.

However, if I were to change `external-library-path` to `library-path` in `HelloWorld/asconfig.json`, then the code from `library` would be embed inside `HelloWorld.swf`, which is not the intended way. I was expecting `HellowWorld.swf` to explicitly import `library.swf`  (via `ImportAssets` tag). I tried tweaking library imports ways and static link, but none of the ways lead to wanted behavior.

How can I achieve this?

*Extra question*: the compiler keeps compiling to `CWS`, how can I compile it uncompressed?

Comment: Hello again. I think I understand now what you are trying to achieve, but it is not actually achievable: you cannot build a project with RSL classes in the external SWF and expect that project to **automatically** load the referred classes from the outside... somehow. You either build a complete and one application with all the classes (I recommend this one) or alternately you build your app with RSL classes then your app loads that RSL SWF in runtime.

Comment: @Organis Hello :) Let's say my goal is to modify UI of one application, and their SWFs are built the way I describe. Now, I realize there is some sort of wrapper involved to load library first, but I thought I could compile without wrapper. And to mention it again, the app uses [`ImportAssets2`](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2887%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C52%2C529%2C0%5D) tag to load library, so I assumed **automatic** load is possible, eh.

Comment: No, I don't think it works this way. It's more like a **promise**, you assure the compiler that some symbol (a Library item or AS3 class) **will** be available inside the **ApplicationDomain** and **Security** sandbox at the moment the main application needs them. This way Flash IDE allows you to make designs with shared resources and Flash compiler overlooks the absence of the said resources. Still, it's up to you to sentiently provide these **promised** resources.

Comment: @Organis "app uses ImportAssets2" meant to be `SWFs use ImportAssets2 tag to load library.swf`. I know this because I looked in JPEXS Decompiler. But I see :( Any suggestions how I can setup a dummy application to achieve this behavior?

Comment: How to put it... I professionally worked with Flash from 2001 to 2017, and I never, **not even once**, encountered an application that somehow magically shared content between two SWF modules without one obviously loading another. So, I think, compile main app with **external-library-path** to the library then before any other script executes make main app load the **library.swf** via **Loader** (read about second argument of the **Loader.load(...)** method) into the same **ApplicationDomain** and **SecurityDomain**.

Comment: @Organis wait, when you are referring to `magically share`, are you talking about importing `library.swf` inside e.g. `HelloWorld.swf`? Because this sounds logically and not that magically :)

Comment: No, by **magically share** I mean what you expecting from that **ImportAssets2** SWF tag: content from **library.swf** somehow appears in other SWF without obvious loading or embedding **library.swf** into the other one.

Comment: @Organis I expected it to be like a .dll import in .exe in a way that you don't necessarily embed it in the binary. And I personally understand this linkage via asset import as "obvious loading". I'm surprised you say it is not :/

Comment: **AS3** is not a system-level language like **C++** or **Delphi**. First and foremost it was intended to be loaded and work in a browser's plugin sandbox with zero to none guaranties that any additional downloads (from host server) actually succeed. Thus, **AS3**, more or less, allows you to load and use external assets like images and content libraries (more) and additional functionality and scripts (less), but you are the one responsible for loading them and also handling the exceptions. So, no, they are not expected to work in a similar way as **Windows' EXE** and **DLL** work together.

Comment: @Organis I see... The app in question is a mobile app so I guess it has a parent wrap to load stuff. Soo, any suggestions how I can setup a project to achieve this behavior? Although I might fallback to just batch editing tags with some command-line script...

Comment: I already said that above. I recommend building a single application with all the code bundled together. However, if you still are willing to have **library.swf** as a separate file, then build with **external-library-path** on and set your main app to load **library.swf** (first and foremost and before anything else and with error handling) into the same application/security domain so that runtime shared resources are actually available for the main app when it gets to referring them.

Comment: @Organis with my goal to modify the _existing_ UI of an app (that already handles library loading) I have to replicate the same build results they have - library.swf and ImportAsset. Or ignore library and embed all code needed in every SWF but the price is size... Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and explanations!